# java equivalent to __func__

Tags: java, reflection, func

```
#include <stdio.h>
void someFunc(void) {
  printf("%s\n"), __func__);
}
```

Each time the function is called it will print:

```
someFunc
```

What is the java equivalent?

I have found

```
(new Exception()).getStackTrace()[0].getMethodName()
```

And

```
java.lang.Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName()
```

But these just seem ridiculous, is there an easier way?

Comment: Don't expect Java to have direct equivalents to all C++ constructs, or vice-versa.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there's no easier way. As Java doesn't have a macro facility, there's nothing directly equivalent to the C++ version.

Comment: Technically speaking, `__func__` is not a preprocessor macro - the C or C++ preprocessor has no concept of functions. It's implemented by the compiler itself.

Answer (score 2):

With a bit of configuration you could set up something like [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/) with a pattern that includes the method name (and any other details you want), then all you have to do is something like:

```
private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class);

void someMethod() {
    log.info("text");
}
```

The benefit here is that you do the setup once, and then you can reuse the logger in as many different places as you want.

Answer (score 2):

You may use log4j and use %M patter to output the method name, when needed -> http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html

The documentation, though, has this warning:

> WARNING Generating caller location
>   information is extremely slow and
>   should be avoided unless execution
>   speed is not an issue.

They probably use the trick similar to your `(new Exception()).getStackTrace()[0].getMethodName()`, but this is a very slow call to use in every log statement.

On the other hand log4j is highly customizable and you may add the method name output to a subset of your code that is not performance critical.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is No.

Incidentally, the two approaches you've found are essentially equivalent.  If `t` is the current thread, then `t.getStackTrace()` works by creating an instance of `Exception` and calling `getStaceTrace()` on it.

As others have noted, creating an `Exception` to capture the stacktrace is an expensive operation in Java, so you should do this WITH CAUTION.

Answer (score 0):

Another ridiculous way for receiving the `java.lang.reflect.Method` of the enclosing method would be:

```
void someMethod() {
    class A{}
    Method thisMethod = A.class.getEnclosingMethod();
}
```

This way you can not only find the method name, but also other interesting features of the method such as annotations, parameterized types, etc.

I wish there has been a more built-in way of acquiring metadata at runtime...